# Installshield error 1309.Error reading from file

Tags: installshield

I have a Basic MSI Project.

I have three discs I am going to span the content on for the release.
I have three features I am using for this, each with their own individual content.
I use the project assistant->Application Files tab to select each feature and add content to them. When I drop-down the "All Application Data: tab, I drop down the items therein, and it looks great...

I then use the release wizard to begin creating my three discs. So I use custom disc spanning, and create three CDs with the default value for the names ("DISC?" which is equivalent to the current disc it is.. ex: DISC1). I then put each feature under each disc. One feature per disc... total: three discs and three features... It output those folders labeled as "DISC1", "DISC2", and "DISC3". I then proceeded to burn each folder onto each disc as such: "DISC1" folder copied and burned to disc with the disc labeled as "DISK1".

It seemed like a dream come true.. everything was going so smoothly, until...

I launched the install on the first disc... and when it prompted to insert the next disc, I did so, then it gave the error: "Error 1309.Error reading from file"

It recognizes that it should continue to the next disc to continue the install, and then when I insert the next disc, it gives the error that it cannot locate the data from disc 2 because it is looking in the filepath for disc 1 (ie "E:\DISK1\data.txt")

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Installer has a bug / feature limitation.  When you burn your disc, your CD volume label has to match excactly what MSI is expecting the label to be.   So if your Media table says DISK1, DISK2, DISK3  that's how your CD's have to be burned.

Comment: That is exactly what I did.. that is what is confusing me... I burned each disc as "DISK1" and put the folder from my release "DISK1" and burned them. I did the same thing for the other discs.. burned "DISK2" with the folder "DISK2" from release... I am at a loss...?

Comment: It does indeed detect that the correct disc has been inserted, then it tried to read from it, only to find out that the content is not on there. It looks in the directory "E:\DISK1\etc\etc\" which signifies that the setup is looking for the file in the wrong location.. (but still knows that the next disc needs to be inserted to continue to access it) I do not understand the logic.

Comment: Ok, in your question you said InstallShield created folders "DISC1" "DISC2" "DISC3" and that you burned the CD's as "DISK1" "DISK2" and "DISK3".   (Notice the difference.) Take a look at the MSI on DISK1 with ORCA and go to the Media table.   What do you see VolumeLabel column for the various rows?

Comment: I did type that in my initial question...my mistake.. but I have verified that the folder name matches with the volume label with the dvd. I am looking into the MSI on DISK1 with ORCA...will keep you posted :)

Comment: Ok, opened .msi with Orca. Volume Label for the first is "DISK1" and the second is "DISK2". It is as I expected... but for some reason when I burn the folder "DISK1" to the DVD labeled "DISK1" and I burn the folder "DISK2" to the dvd labeled "DISK2" it attempts to locate the media that is on DISK2 within the filepath for DISK1. I tried various combinations of adding the features and content. None have worked so far. Is there some fundamental process I am neglecting? Thanks.

Comment: Short of something silly like burning a DISK1 folder *IN* the DISK1 CDROM (don't laugh: I have a CM / Media Control team that's been known to do this on occasion ) or failing to burn all of the files or mangling long file names... I'm not aware of any issues.   Have you logged the installer to see if you can get more information?

Comment: I accidentally burned the DISK1 folders in the DISK1 CDROM. I didn't notice it until a short while ago.. heh. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yup, seen that one before.  Mind upping and accepting my answer(s)?

Comment: Sure thing, I'm still a bit new.

Comment: Is there  a way to deliver only the .msi file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's take another angle.   Have you confirmed the burned CD's are good?  Perform MD5 hashes of all the files?    What happens if you create an INSTALL folder on your harddrive and consolidate all of the files into a single structure and run it there.  Does it succeed?

Also, are you comperessing into CAB's or are you doing uncompressed?   If uncompressed, have you tried compressed?  Also are you doing uncompressed are you consuming any merge modules?   Have you run Validation on the MSI to identify any issues?

Also checkout: [Additional Causes for 1308 and 1309 Error Messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/02/28/540960.aspx)

Comment: Christopher, I want to thank you for helping with me through this. I found the problem. When compiling for the release, it output three folders, DISK1, DISK2, and DISK3. While I did burn the DVD's with the correct volume name, I copied over the "DISK1" folder over to the explorer window and then proceeded to burn. That was my mistake. Instead, I should have copied all of the contents OF DISK1 over to the explorer window, then burned them. I tried this, and it prompted for the next disc and then found them when I inserted and finished installation! Thanks for your patience Chris!